# Google cloud messaging using Push sharp

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I am using https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Registration with GCM works fine, however if I unregister, the device still receives push notifications.

All I have done is downloaded the push sharp source from https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp, and replaced my project ID as suggested in the example solution.

Could anyone familiar with GCM please suggest if they have experience anything similar, which is after unregistering, they still receive push notification from Google, and suggest a workaround/fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem have two solutions :

1. On Unregister mark registration false for that device on your server database.Or,
2. unregister broadcastreceiver from your app.